# Android gradle build System.getEnv("RELEASE_PASSWORD") returns null

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having an issues where System.getenv() is returning null for the environment variable. My password is stored in the *RELEASE_PASSWORD* environment variable. When I do:

`$ echo $RELEASE_PASSWORD`

it prints out the correct value, so I know the variable is set.

I was originally setting the `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` in the *release* buildType and everything was working fine, but I need different signing configs for different product flavors. If I hardcode the password, it works just like it is suppose to. Things only get wonky when I try to read the password from an environment variable.

Is it some sort of scope issue?

This is what I currently have in my `build.gradle`.

```
android {

  ...

  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile ...;
      keyAlias ...;
      storePassword System.getenv("RELEASE_PASSWORD");
      keyPassword System.getenv("RELEASE_PASSWORD");
    }

    unsigned {
      keyAlias "";
      storePassword "";
      keyPassword "";
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      versionNameSuffix = "-DEBUG"
    }

    release {
    }
  }

  flavorGroups "storeFront"

  productFlavors {
    def googleVariable = signingConfigs.release
    def amazonVariable = signingConfigs.unsigned

    google {
        flavorGroup "storeFront"
        signingConfig googleVariable
    }

    amazon {
        flavorGroup "storeFront"
        signingConfig amazonVariable
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android Studio doesn't pass environment variables to Gradle, so what you're trying to do won't work from the IDE. If you want a way to avoid keeping the keystore password in the build file, here's an answer with code for saving it in a separate file:

[Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle/20573171#20573171)

Comment: Thanks! Now that I think about it, I wasn't doing the googleRelease build from Android Studio, so I was never hitting this issue before. The person who actually built the release apks was doing it from the command line. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Scott, do you know why Android Studio doesn't pass environment variables to Gradle?  Or a workaround for this?

Comment: I think this changed. For me (using Windows) it was enough to just restart Android Studio.

Comment: No longer (ever?) true. You just aren't getting the env vars you think you should be. See these answers from similar questions (OS X) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30128305/1650674 (Linux) http://stackoverflow.com/a/27795843

Comment: The same applies for IntellijIdea on Ubuntu 18. If I run `./gradlew -q printJavaHome` it works, where in IDE it's "null" if I click "build" from the Gradle menu. In IDE's terminal it works also.

Comment: A good, Gradle-friendly alternative is to add username and password credentials in the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file (i.e. outside of your Android projects) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38046724/1071320) in the same thread which Scott Barta has linked to.

Answer (score 18):

You can run Android Studio from the command-line to get the environment variables passed into the IDE. In Mac OS you can run it from a terminal by running `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

Comment: I came to this answer myself today. This is unfortunately the only way I have found so far to use env variables in gradle scripts...

Comment: Yeah on our Bamboo build server it works fine because of the command line, but not on my dev iMac :<

Answer (score 17):

For a Windows user, if you make a new environment variable, you need to restart your PC. I don't know what's wrong with Windows, But that's how it works on it. What I tried is, In my gradle script I wrote a task to print my `JAVA_HOME` variable path like this:

```
task printJavaHome{
     println System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") 
}
```

and then synchronized with gradle.

Then open terminal window in your Studio.

and type:

```
gradlew -q printJavaHome
```

This will show your java home path if you set it otherwise it'll print `null`.

and before executing the above command, make sure the terminal is pointed at the root directory of the project.

Now try setting a new environment variable and load it, and try to print it as  mentioned steps above. You'll see null if you're using Windows. But when will you restart PC and again execute the command, it'll then return your environment variable's actual value.

That's what I experienced and thought of sharing, might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 3):

For me (using Windows) it was enough to just **restart Android Studio**.

Comment: If this doesn't help then restart your windows. That worked for me while you don't have admin credentials and you set user's environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Android studio needs to be closed and restarted to recognize newly changed or added environment variables.

For some reason, I don't think that the operation "Invalidate Cache and restart" picks up new environment variables. I had done that a couple of times, and I don't think I got the new values doing that operation.  That sounds hard for me to believe, so maybe I had some typo error and I'm confused on what I observed; but I did checked out the spelling a number of times, because that's the obvious cause. Without making any changes the problem I was having reading environment variables went away after doing a full close of android studio as opposed to doing an Invalidate Cache and restart operation.
 The reason I did an Invalidate Cache and restart operation, was because I had several Android Studio sessions going and that seems like a simple way to close them all and get them all restarted.

Answer (score 0):

After I added new env variables I invalidated the IDE (Android Studio 4.0) caches. You can find this option in menu File.

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...