# Access to environment variables from Android Studio gradle build

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, environment-variables, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Gradle build I need to get access to environment variables I set from `.bash.profile`. It works fine when I build from command line - Gradle script can see all the variables.

However, when I try to run my build from Android Studio - I don't have my environment variables anymore.

Here is a rough picture of what I'm facing:

1) Set custom environment variable via `~/.bash.profile`:

```
export MY_CUSTOM_VAR='Hello World'
```

2) In `build.gradle` create task which prints this environment variable:

```
task printVar << {
    println System.getenv("MY_CUSTOM_VAR")
}
```

3) execute `printVar` from command line. Output is correct - env variable is set:

output: `Hello World`

4) execute `printVar` from Android Studio. Environment variable **is not set**. Output is empty

Common sense tells me that by doing `export MY_CUSTOM_VAR='Hello World'` I just make this variable available to shell process (and its subprocesses). And it would probable work if I launch my Android Studio from command line (so it would inherit my environment). But since I launch Android Studio from dock (i'm on Mac by the way) - it has its own environment which doesn't have any idea about my `~/.bash.profile`.

Is there any way I can populate custom environment variables to Android Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android gradle build System.getEnv("RELEASE\_PASSWORD") returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818393/android-gradle-build-system-getenvrelease-password-returns-null)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variable in settings.gradle not working with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173826/environment-variable-in-settings-gradle-not-working-with-android-studio)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found an answer here:
[Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x)

Essentially, you need to also set environment variables used by `launchd` via `launchctl` - this way environment variable will be available for anything launched from MacOS UI

So I modified my `~/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
export MY_CUSTOM_VAR='Hello World'
launchctl setenv MY_CUSTOM_VAR $MY_CUSTOM_VAR
```

Comment: don't forget to run "$ source .bash_profile" and restart Android Studio! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment used by launchd (and, by extension, anything started from Spotlight) with launchctl setenv. For example to set the path:

`launchctl setenv MY_CUSTOM_VAR /***/***/***`

To keep changes after a reboot you can set the environment variables from /etc/launchd.conf, like so:

`setenv MY_CUSTOM_VAR /***/***/***`

you can see [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/3756686#3756686)