# How to store app keys in a separate file locally and load from there in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I have some keys or app_id, for instance, fabric app_id, in my build.gradle, different for different build like -

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon     : "@mipmap/kj_launcher",
                    roundappIcon: "@mipmap/kj_launcher",
                    fabric_id: "fabric_app_id"
            ]
```

which I indirectly use in AndroidManifest file.

So, my question is, a way to store that fabric_id inside any file which is present locally in my system and then load it over here in the above code, different for the different build?

Just like we do in .properties file and get the value from that inside build.gradle.

I don't want to expose these ids.

Comment: Fetching system variables is common practice and should accomplish what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589052/proper-way-to-use-system-environment-variables-in-gradle-using-android-studio/34640602

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to do this, but the way I do this is to define it the `gradle.properties` file.

In my local `gradle.properties` file:

```
MY_SECRET_API_KEY=Dev_Api_Key_That_I_Dont_Care_If_Devs_Have_Access_To
```

Then on my CI build server, I have a script that replaces `Dev_Api_Key_That_I_Dont_Care_If_Devs_Have_Access_To` with a value of the production API key.