# Android Studio does not honor environment variables

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to pass environment specific values to Android studio v 2.2.2 (such as server url, keystore location and password) by setting java vm arguments. So far I've tried following options but nothing has worked.

**1. Setting the java-vm arguments from studio.vmoptions (as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#customize_vm))**

I clicked `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options...` to create a new vmoptions file which is created at ~/.AndroidStudio2.2/studio64.vmoptions. I have edited the file to add following line.

`-DRELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH=/home/ubuntu/ks/myapp/app-release.keystore`

**2. With a `gradle.properties` file**

I have created a gradle.properties file in the same directory where the root build.gradle file exists. The file has following contents.

`RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH=/home/ubuntu/ks/myapp/app-release.keystore`

**3. Edited the studio.sh file**

I have also tried editing the studio.sh file, added following line hoping these properties will be available to Android Studio.

`export RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH=/home/ubuntu/ks/myapp/app-release.keystore`

My build.gradle file has signingConfig section where this value is used.

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(System.env.RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH)
            storePassword System.env.RELEASE_KEYS_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias System.env.RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword System.env.RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```

The build fails when gradle project sync / build runs from Android Studio.

The error is displayed: `Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='/home/ubuntu/path-to-project'.` This means that script is not able to resolve the file path as it is coming null.

**UPDATE**
If I run the gradle build from command line it perfectly works, build succeeds, all I have to do is just fire some export commands for the desired properties I want to inherit in build.

Following is my dev environment:

- Gradle version used by Android Studio: 2.14.1
- Gradle plugin version: 2.3.1
- Android Studio version: 2.2.2
- Java version: oracle jdk 1.8.0_111
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 amd64

Comment: When you tried the Gradle option, did you do `System.env.RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH` or just `RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH`?  It should be the second one since it's not an environment variable.

Comment: What do you mean by the maven option? setting props in the gradle.properties file?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant Gradle option (#2).

Comment: Oh! I am using `System.env.RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH` in build script. If I use just `RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PATH` it works in Android Studio but now the build fails in command line.

Comment: Gradle does not have access to environment variables when launched from Android Studio. Gradle does have access to environment variables when run elsewhere (command line, CI server, etc.).

Comment: So how to write a script which will work for command line as well as within the Android Studio?

Comment: The variables should be taken from the `gradle.properties` file from both the project and home `gradle` directory (on Mac it's at `~/.gradle`. It wouldn't matter where the build happened.  I would look at those to make sure it's correct.

Comment: The Android Studio problem is resolved but now there is another problem, the CL build fails with error `Failed to read key relase_key from store "/home/ubuntu/ks/myapp/app-release.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`. Looks like the gradle when run from CL can resolve the path but fails to read key from KS.

Comment: maybe my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38046932/4758255 will be helpful to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variable in settings.gradle not working with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173826/environment-variable-in-settings-gradle-not-working-with-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I have done investigation based on the comments by @DeeV and @CommonsWare and have done some changes to run the build successfully on Android Studio as well as on command line.

1. I have placed gradle.properties file in Gradle's home directory. In my environment (ubuntu) the gradle home directory is located at `~/.gradle`.
2. I have to remove the `System.env.` from the usage of the variables, so this way it uses the properties declared in gradle.properties file.

With these two changes, I noticed that the Android Studio problem got resolved. However this has caused another problem, the CL build was failing with error:
 `Failed to read key relase_key from store "/home/ubuntu/ks/myapp/app-release.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.` This means the gradle when run from CL can resolve the path but fails to read key from KS.

I have to do the following step to get rid of this error:

3. In the gradle.properties, I had put the values for `RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD` and `RELEASE_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD` in double quotes, I removed the quotes and then the build completed successfully from command line.

I hope this will help anyone who face similar situation.